# How to get path to base Symfony folder with javascript?

Tags: javascript, symfony

I'm wondering about how to get an access to the folder with directory:

```
Project/upload/pictures/
```

with js ("Project" is a Symfony project's base folder). With PHP it was simple it was enough to write:

```
../upload/pictures/
```

but in javascript it only works until I click on the link with path() twig function. After then this way stops working. My code:

```
$("#menu_user_item1 img").attr("src","../resources/user/"+id2+"/pictures/logo.jpg");
```

id2 is an ajax respond from PHP

So, how do I can get to such directories? I couldn't find similar question on the Stack. I apologize in advance for my bad English.

Comment: Have a look to : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing/generate_url_javascript.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your upload directory isn't in /public, use simlink :)

Comment: But how to use it, especially for getting to: Project/upload/pictures/ directory?

Comment: OK I found it's at https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html  in makePathRelative section. Then it is enough to send generated path via Ajax